# Making HTTP Requests API Calls

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following code in the IOS SDK I am building:

```
+ (void) makeRequestToEndPoint:(NSString *) endpoint values:(NSMutableDictionary *) params onCompletion:(SDKCompletionBlock) responseHandler
{
    [params setObject: key forKey: @"key"];

    NSString * urlString = [self createApiUrlFromEndpoint: endpoint];
    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString: urlString];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: url];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"charset" forHTTPHeaderField:@"utf-8"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    request.HTTPBody = [[params urlEncodedString] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
    {

        NSError * dicError = nil;
        NSDictionary * dictionary = nil;

        if([data length] >= 1) {
            dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options:kNilOptions error: &dicError];
        }

        responseHandler(dictionary, error);
    }];

}
```

So that people using the SDK can make API calls by doing the following:

[SDK makeRequestToEndpoint: @]

What is the best way to structure (best way to handle error handling, response handling, etc) the code above to make easy for people to use the SDK?

Comment: What's wrong with `SDKCompletionBlock` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many open source frameworks from which you can learn good design practices for asynchronous networking.  I recommend you take a look at

- [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)